# Is there better explaination of the WCF RIA Services Library Project structure?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wcf-ria-services

When you create WCF RIA Services Library Project then two projects appears.

1. RIAServicesLibrary1
2. RIAServicesLibrary1.Web

It's clear for me what for we need RIAServicesLibrary1.Web project to keep stuff like 
`LinqToEntitiesDomainService`?

But my questions is: how we can use RIAServicesLibrary project? Is any real sense of it usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RIAServicesLibrary can be used for directly referencing in client applications that do not need to have to be deployed in a multi-tier environment (client-server). As soon as you want to have your client talk to a webservice on a central server you will communicate to the .Web variant, which has a direct reference to the library project.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input! So Do we have to put some special code into the RIAServicesLibrary project?  How  we can to use it actually?

Comment: Your Ria Service library will just contain your domain model, expressed in Entities. If you use Entity Framework, your edmx files will end up in the service library. No special code required.

Comment: What if I want to have some biggest level of abstraction over the entity model? I mean some kind of super class that includes a lot of individual entities? Do have I use WCF RIA Services level for it? Or it's better to create some SQL Server Views?

Comment: Personally, I would create another service layer to achieve that, consuming the Entities, exposing super-services with bigger granularity.